# Git Flow. How to get the functionality/code of the first branch to develop the second branch

Tags: git, git-flow

How to get the functionality of the first branch to develop the second branch?

Both features were branched from develop

Comment: Merge the branch with the required functionality into your new branch.

Comment: I have two branches now. One is done, second - almost done, but it needs work using a functional first branch. If I do like u said I will have a new branch which doesn't have a functional of the second branch....if I got u right

Comment: Or u mean?
When I'm on second-feature just do this? 
git merge first-feature

Answer (score 1):

Rebase B onto A so you can work with the A functionality present. After A is merged, B will be rebased onto the merge commit on `develop` so it will keep working without including A.